# How do I access a .xul file using a chrome:// URL?

Tags: firefox, xul

I'm learning how to make firefox extensions.

I have created a directory called findfile, under which I have the directories content/ skin/ and locale/ . There is a findfile.xul file in the content/ directory. The other two are empty

I have placed a findfile.manifest file under /home/akshay/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx.dev/chrome/

The content of findfile.manifest is:

```
content findfile file:///home/akshay/programs/firefox/findfile/content/
skin findfile classic/1.0 file:///home/akshay/programs/firefox/findfile/skin/
locale findfile en-US file:///home/akshay/programs/firefox/findfile/locale/
```

When I access findfile.xul using a file:// URL, it works fine. But when I try to access it using chrome://findfile/content/findfile.xul, it doesn't show the window. (I restarted the browser)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the chrome URL you are using?

Comment: chrome://findfile/content/findfile.xul

I also tried the Chrome List extension, it doesn't show up

Comment: why community wiki? this is a legit question...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps rename the findfile.manifest to chrome.manifest ?

Also not a good idea to give absolute paths. Use relative paths instead.